# File not found error using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to use `MafftCommandline` to align my data, but i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "C:\Users\Rimvis\Desktop\asd\bioinformatika2_Working.py", line 35, in <mo
dule>
    stdout, stderr = mafftCline()  # Note that MAFFT will write the alignment to
 stdout, which you may want to save to a file and then parse
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\Application\__init__.py", line 475, in
 __call__
    shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

my code is as following :

```
dataToProcess = "dataToProcess.fa"
file = open(dataToProcess, "w")

arrayOfSequences = []
for sequence in blast.alignments:
    if sequence.length > blast.alignments[0].length * 80 / 100:
        sequenceToAppend = SeqRecord(Seq(sequence.hsps[0].sbjct), id=sequence.title)
        arrayOfSequences.append(sequenceToAppend)
SeqIO.write(arrayOfSequences, file, "fasta")
file.close()

maffPath = "..\mafft-win\mafft.bat"     
mafftCline = MafftCommandline(maffPath, input=dataToProcess)
stdout, stderr = mafftCline()  # Note that MAFFT will write the alignment to stdout, which you may want to save to a file and then parse
alignedData = "aligned.fa"
alignedFile = open(alignedData, "w") 
alignedFile.write(stdout) 
alignedFile.close() 
aligned = AlignIO.read(alignedData, "fasta")
```

i was using [this](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.Applications._Mafft.MafftCommandline-class.html) tutorial as an example

Comment: Try using the absolute path for the file and not just the file name and see if that clears up the issue.  The application might be looking in a different location than the run directory for your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@willOEM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458983/willoem) has said, the script is looking for a file in a relative directory.

Your script assumes that its file is located in the same directory as your "dataToProcess" fasta file.

If you have moved your script or are trying to open a file located elsewhere then it will raise this error.

You'll need to change your `dataToProcess`, `maffPath` and `alignedFile` to refer to the absolute path.

Comment: But i also had to add full paths, so thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i needed to escape slashes.
And use `maffPath = "..\\mafft-win\\mafft.bat"` instead of `maffPath = "..\mafft-win\mafft.bat"`